# How to use python output xml content in html?

Tags: python, html, xml

So i have received this question from my lecturer, but i have no idea about this, anyone have any experience about this type of question?

I need to use the python to output the xml content in HTML. And i am using the Visual studio code, any suggest to run this type of question and how to run it?

This is my xml code

```
<record>
   <restaurant name="La Pasteria" rate="1">
      <cuisine id="-">Italian</cuisine>
      <address>8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor</address>
      <capacity>300</capacity>
      <phone>06-2899808</phone>
      <phone>06-2829818</phone>
         <general>-</general>
         <shop1>-</shop1>
         <shop2>-</shop2>
   </restaurant>
   <restaurant name="Nyonya Baba" rate="2">
      <cuisine id="112">Malaysian</cuisine>
      <address>21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka</address>
      <address>25, Jalan Bukit Beruang, 75450 Melaka</address>
      <capacity>80</capacity>
      <phone>
      <general>012-2677498</general>
         <shop1>06-2855413</shop1>
         <shop2>06-2856418</shop2>
      </phone>
   </restaurant>
   <restaurant name="Malaya Food" rate="5">
      <cuisine id="115">Malaysian</cuisine>
      <address>22, Jalan Ayer Keroh, 7520 Melaka</address>
      <capacity>50</capacity>
      <phone>06-2723603</phone>
         <general>-</general>
         <shop1>-</shop1>
         <shop2>-</shop2>
   </restaurant>
</record>
```

Comment: "use the python to output the xml content in HTML" is unclear. Please provide more details.

Comment: Here is what i get from my lecturer
"Use the python code to display the XML content of the restaurant name and address of all restaurants in HTML file."
And i ask again to explain about the question and my lecturer give me "Given XML, use python to display the required output in HTML."

Comment: what you need to do is parse the xml and generate HTML. You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html for xml parsing. Next you need to create HTML table. You can do that with Jinja2 - https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/